# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for Existing an Envelope for a Parametric Family of Implicit Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, implicit-function-theorem, singularity-theory

Let $F(x, y, z, \lambda)=0$ be a parametric family of implicit surfaces. Sometimes the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)#Envelope_of_a_family_of_surfaces) of the family exists as another surface, but at other times it may degenerate to a curve or a point, or even it can be empty.

Is there any know condition that guaranteed the existence of the envelope as a surface?

Comment: You did not search this site very well. Here are various links to my own answers (some in the case of curves, but you can easily generalize): [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4462094/71348),  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1761697/71348), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402038/71348).

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you for your comment. What would be a good book to learn this stuff? None of the undergraduate DG books that I found does not discuss this topic.

Comment: I don’t know any modern DG books that treat this topic. The implicit function theorem is the necessary tool. The result in my posts appears as an exercise in my Multivariable Mathematics text.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I see. It is on page number 261. Yet it is unclear to me how this generalizes to a family of surfaces as the analogous matrix is not a square matrix. Do you mind writing a complete solution to this? It would be beneficial for lots of others as well.

Comment: Sorry. I didn’t pay enough attention. I was expecting two parameters. What even is the definition if the envelope in your case?

Comment: @TedShifrin: "locus of characteristic curves"

Comment: Please edit your post to include a detailed definition. This is not something I'm familiar with outside of PDE.